# Can't work out why this function doesn't work. Loading content via ajax/jquery and it doesn't load

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, jquery

It's probably something stupid I've done but I can't work it out. Heres the function:

```
function loadguides(softwareid){
            var $softwareid = $('#'+softwareid); 
            $softwareid.load("devices/" + phoneid + firmwareid + ".html " + "#" + softwareid);
        }
        loadguides('ms1');
        loadguides('ms2');
        loadguides('ms3');
        loadguides('ms4');
        loadguides('ms5');
        loadguides('ps1');
        loadguides('ps2');
        loadguides('ps3');
```

If you need more of the code just ask which parts. To give a comparison, this works:

```
loadtab('mac');
    loadtab('pc');
    loadtab('linux');
    loadtab('safari');
    loadtab('redsn0wM');
    loadtab('redsn0wP');
    loadtab('pwnagetool');
    loadtab('limera1n');
    loadtab('greenpois0n');
    loadtab('spiritM');
    loadtab('spiritP');
    loadtab('sn0wbreeze');

    function loadtab(tab){
        var $tab = $('#'+tab);
        $tab.hide();
        $tab.load("devices/" + phoneid + firmwareid + ".html " + "#" + tab,
        function(){
            var tabcontent = $("#"+tab).text();
            if (tabcontent == "1"){
                $tab.show();
            }
            else{
                $tab.hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear on what the problem is. Are you getting an error? Does it just simply not load?
It does not appear that you have phoneid or firmwareid JS variables defined.

BTW, you can post your full code on: http://jsfiddle.net

I would install/use Firebug and look at the console to determine if there is a javascript or network error.

Answer (score 0):

should your function declaration go above where you are calling it?  For example:

```
function loadtab(tab){
    var $tab = $('#'+tab);
    $tab.hide();
    $tab.load("devices/" + phoneid + firmwareid + ".html " + "#" + tab,
    function(){
        var tabcontent = $("#"+tab).text();
        if (tabcontent == "1"){
            $tab.show();
        }
        else{
            $tab.hide();
        }
    });
}
loadtab('mac');
loadtab('pc');
loadtab('linux');
loadtab('safari');
loadtab('redsn0wM');
loadtab('redsn0wP');
loadtab('pwnagetool');
loadtab('limera1n');
loadtab('greenpois0n');
loadtab('spiritM');
loadtab('spiritP');
loadtab('sn0wbreeze');
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, functions are parsed before the code is run. If the OP had done something like `var loadtab = function() {}`, that would need to be before its usage